# How many different arrangements of triangles that are either red or blue around a regular heptagon are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I have the following problem

I have an yellow heptagon (regular $7$ sided polygon)

Against every side there is a triangle.

The triangle is either red or blue.

How many different arrangements of triangles around the heptagon are possible?

arrangements that are rotational variants don't count,
arrangements that are mirror variants can count

so going clockwise and having counted red-red-red-blue-red-blue-blue as arrangement

then red-red-blue-red-blue-blue-red is the same arrangement and does not count (it is the  same arrangement rotated a bit)

red-red-blue-blue-red-blue-red is not the same arrangement (but is a mirror)

Related

and how many when we also discard the mirror arrangements?

Comment: So how far have you got? Suppose there is just one red triangle. How many arrangements are possible? What about two red triangles?

Comment: iF i am correct there is only one without red triange, one with one triangle, 3 with two triangles,  and 6 with three triangles, by number of blue triangles
(0)rrrrrrr (1)rrrrrrb (2)rrrrrbb,rrrrbrb, rrrbrrb
(3)rrrrbbb, rrrbrbb, rrbrrbb, rrbrbrb, rrbbrrb, rrrbbrb

Comment: You are almost there. But I think you have some duplicates in your 4 red, 3 blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $7$ is prime, there are no periods other than $1$ and $7$. There are $2$ arrangements with period $1$, so the remaining $2^7-2$ arrangements have period $7$. Thus there are

$$
2+\frac{2^7-2}7=20
$$

rotationally inequivalent arrangements.

The orbits under the full symmetry group including reflections can be counted using [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma). The identity leaves $2^7$ arrangements invariant, each of $6$ rotations leaves $2$ arrangements invariant and each of $7$ reflections leaves $2^4$ arrangements invariant, so there are

$$
\frac{2^7+6\cdot2+7\cdot2^4}{14}=18
$$

inequivalent arrangements.